# Returning shape.area in code block of ArcGIS Field Calculator with if statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, python-parser

Using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop, I try to calculate a field using an 'if' statement in the field calculator.
Here is my code  :

```
"
#Expression
MyField_2 = def Reclass(!MyField_1!)

#Parser
Python 9.3

#Code Block
def Reclass(MyField1) :
    if MyField1 == -1 :
        return 0
    else :
        return !shape.area!
"
```

But I have an error returning !shape.area!.
How can I fix that ?

Comment: I think `!shape.area!` also needs to be an argument in your `Reclass` function. But can you please post the error?

Comment: I have a 00089 error "Python parsing error line 5"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shape_area` has to be an argument in your `Reclass` function.

Your expression should look like this:

```
Reclass( !MyField_1!,!shape.area!)
```

And your script code like this:

```
def Reclass(MyField1,shape_area):
 if MyField1 == -1:
   return 0
 else:
   return (shape_area)
```

Comment: Great, this works !

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a code block, you should be able to just do...

```
0 if !MyField_1! == -1 else !shape.area!
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving an error because shape isn't being referenced.

One way to solve it would be to pass two parameters to your reclass function, like @ustroetz mentioned. The following code does this:

```
#Expression
Reclass(!MyField_1!, !shape.area!)

#Code block
def Reclass(test_field, shape):
  if test_field == -1:
    return 0
  else:
    return shape

#Or alternatively,
def Reclass(test_field, shape):
  return 0 if test_field == -1 else shape
```